# How to use multiple arguments in a single statement with Go templates

Tags: templates, go

I'm trying to pipe multiple conditions in a single if statement(using [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template) package) which should translate into "**If `$total` == 1 and `has` function returns `false` display `works`**". I don't understand how exactly the pipelines work or why I'm getting this non-sense error. As far as I understand when chaining is used (`|`) it sends the result as argument to the last command (`and` in this case)

```
{{if  eq $total 1 | ne has true | and}}
    Works
{{end}}
```

`err template: :29:26: executing "" at <ne>: wrong number of args for ne: want 2 got 2`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about why the funny error message, but you are actually passing 3 arguments to `ne` which triggers the error :

([from the text/template package](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/))

> A pipeline may be "chained" by separating a sequence of commands with pipeline characters '|'. In a chained pipeline, the result of the each command is passed as the last argument of the following command. The output of the final command in the pipeline is the value of the pipeline.

So you are giving `ne` the result of function `has`, the value `true` and the result of the first expression.

To get what you want do:

```
{{if eq $total 1 | and (not has)}}
    Works
{{end}}
```

This will compare the result of `eq $total 1` (or `$total == 1`) which is passed as the second argument to the `and` and the negated result of `has` and thus only print `Works` when `$total == 1 AND has returns false`.

See a working example [on the Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZC6sT2p7dH). Note that I replaced $total (since I can't tell where you get it from) with a simple struct.

Comment: The link to the working example in the playground is invalid.

Comment: @benjic Tks! Fixed it.

Comment: Is this specific to 2 conditions? What if you have 3 or 4.  ``{if eq $total 1 | not boo| and (not has)}} `` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That does the same thing again -  the first | sends the result of `eq $total 1` to the second expression as it's last argument. Thus you are now giving 2 arguments to `not` which is why you'd get an error. It'll work if you omit `boo` - `{if eq $total 1 | not | and (not has)}}`. Now the 2nd expression negates the result of the first and then passes it as the last argument to the 3rd expression.